# How to set up SSH on Docker container?

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm trying to establish an ssh connection to a Docker container on my local host. I have another installer (SLM-UI Installer by HPE, in case that means anything) that is running on that Docker container and needs to ssh into it.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Install SSH server and create the sshd_config file
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN echo 'root:password' | chpasswd

# Enable password authentication
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Start the SSH server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

My Docker-Compose file looks like this (only host1 is important here):

```
version: '3'
services:
  host1:
    build: 
      context: C:\Users\GavinAn\ssh_ubuntu
      dockerfile: ssh_ubuntu.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5814
      - 30303
      - 30304
      - 30305
      - 2222:22
    command: tail -F anything

  host2:
    image: ubuntu
    ports:
      - 30303
      - 30304
      - 30305
    command: tail -F anything
```

I have put in the IP address of the Docker container, which I got from running `docker inspect` on my local host, and the username/password (root and password, respectively) to the installer where it asks for them. I have also inputted ports 22 and 2222 and the ssh port number. When I try to run it, I get a `dial tcp [IP ADDRESS:PORT]:connect:connection refused` error.

Connecting from my local host through `ssh root@localhost -p 2222` also doesn't work, giving the error `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`.

Comment: What is the main process these containers should be running (hopefully not a meaningless `tail`)?  How would you ssh into that process if you were running it outside of Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command overwrites CMD from docker file and SSH daemon even doesn't start, so remove this line from docker-compose.yaml

```
command: tail -F anything
```

Apart from that create directory to work SSH daemon by adding line inside Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it! I forgot to remove that command after changing images, and didn't even know I had to make a directory to get SSH to work.